# bad request for jquery Ajax to post stringified json data to MVC action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am planning to use ajax call from jquery to post data to the MVC controller. 
I want to pass the string of json objects using JSON.stringify() to the controller but I am continuously getting the 400 bad request. 
Is this bad practice sending string json object? or do i must use the viewmodel ?

My Action in MVC is as below accepting string value as the parameter.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(string values)
    {

        .. do some actions here ...

        return View("Customer");
    }
```

My Ajax call is like below.

```
$("#customer-add-btn").click(function () {

            var data = $('#customer-add-form').serializeArray();
            console.log(data);

            var values = JSON.stringify(data);

            console.log(values);


            $.ajax({
                url: 'Customer/Create',
                data: values,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: values,
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log('success');// do something on success
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log('error');// do something on error
                }
            });
        });
```

and here is the sample of stringified form values.

```
[ {"name":"business_name","value":"adsf"},{"name":"business_phone_number","value":"124"},{"name":"business_contact_number","value":""} ]
```

Comment: Try removing `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` from your `ActionMethod` and `param` is not `string` which is passed though `ajax`. Try receiving it as key value pairs or define it as key value pair class..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("Create", "Customer"))',
                data: { values: JSON.stringify(values) },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log('success');// do something on success
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log('error');// do something on error
                }
            });
```

and serialize it in controller to bind it with the model:

```
var model = new List<ValuesModel>();
                //JavaScript Serializer to bind with Model
                JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer(new SimpleTypeResolver());
                model = jsSerializer.Deserialize<List<ValuesModel>>(values);
```

where `ValuesModel` is

```
public class ValuesModel
    {
        public ValuesModel()
        {
        }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string values { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.. Its really a good idea. Can you please help me with defining what action method looks like ? I tried with the above code but still getting the bad request.

Comment: you need to use `public async Task<ActionResult> Create(string values)` and remove `ValidateAntiForgeryToken`

Comment: You can also use `[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create(List<ValuesModel> values)
        {
         //do something ***
        return View("Customer");
        }`